# ScaleTransform with value 0.8 gives unintended behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, scaletransform

today i run into a very strange problem. if i use ScaleTransform with value 0.8, i dont see a cursor anymore in a **empty** textbox. its an ugly behavior when using tab..

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=zoomer, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=zoomer, Path=Value}"></ScaleTransform>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" />
    </Grid>

    <Slider x:Name="zoomer" Grid.Row="1" Width="125" Value="1" Minimum="0.7" Maximum="2.2" TickFrequency="0.1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

edit:
some more strange things:

if i set the zoom value to 0.9 and put 5spaces in a textbox the cursor disappear. 
if i set the zoom value to 0.9 and put one of the following letters (q,d,g) in a textbox the cursor disappear.

Comment: The cursor is of course there.Try hitting some spaces

Comment: like i wrote. the problem is that i did not see the cursor when the textbox is empty. so if you use tabbing you dont see where you are.

Comment: added some more strange things. i will use scale values from 1 or higher for my projects from now on;

Comment: Here are similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/5180585/620360 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4551351/620360